# Typo in Documentation comments privilege page

Tags: bug, documentation

In the [Documentation Comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/docs-commenting) privilege page, the **How do I comment?** section as:

> **How do I comment?**
>
> Click the `add comment` link. Comments cannot be multi-line, so simply press enter to submit your comment.

But in the discussion page, it is as `add a comment`. Screenshot for reference:

[image: add a comment]

Can the `add comment` changed to `add a comment` in the privilege page.